Flutter AutoTabsScaffold Failed to navigate to specific route
I have home page which includes different pages inside it, app can navigate to every other page except VolunteerDasboardRoute. I don't know why, first it initializes HomeRoute then it should initialize VolunteerDashboardRoute but it gives that error

Failed to navigate to VolunteerDashboardRoute

AutoRoute file

Home AutoTabsScaffold Code
AutoTabsScaffold(
              routes: viewModel.isVolunteer
                  ? _routesForVolunteer
                  : _routesForImpaired,
              backgroundColor: UIHelper.white,
              // body: viewModel.isPageLoading
              //     ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              //     : viewModel.isVolunteer
              //         ? _screensForVolunteer[viewModel.pageIndex]
              //         : _screensForImpaired[viewModel.pageIndex],
              bottomNavigationBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) {
                return CircleNavBar(
                  activeIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,
                  activeIcons: viewModel.isVolunteer
                      ? _activeIconsForVolunteer
                      : _activeIconsForImpaired,
                  inactiveIcons: viewModel.isVolunteer
                      ? _inactiveIconsForVolunteer
                      : _inactiveIconsForImpaired,
                  height: 70,
                  circleWidth: 62,
                  onTap: tabsRouter.setActiveIndex,
                  color: UIHelper.blackOut,
                  cornerRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(16),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(16),
                  ),
                  shadowColor: UIHelper.formalGrey,
                  elevation: 10,
                );
              },
            )

         List<PageRouteInfo<dynamic>> _routesForImpaired = [
         const ImpairedDashboardRoute(),
          const CameraRoute(),
          const SettingsRoute(),
        ];

        List<PageRouteInfo<dynamic>> _routesForVolunteer = [
          const VolunteerDashboardRoute(),
          const SettingsRoute(),
        ];

